# Error while installing ruby2 with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I was trying to install it this way:

> brew install autoconf brew install automake brew install libyaml rvm
>   install ruby-head

I was trying to install ruby2 with rvm but I got this error:

> ruby-head - #compiling  Error running 'make ', please read
>   /Users/boti/.rvm/log/ruby-head/make.log There has been an error while
>   running make. Halting the installation. Ruby 'ruby-head' was build
>   using clang - but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors.

This is my compiling log:

> compiling ./missing/setproctitle.c compiling dmyext.c linking miniruby
>   /Users/boti/.rvm/src/ruby-head/lib/fileutils.rb:111: [BUG] Stack
>   consistency error (sp: 38, bp: 36) ruby 2.0.0dev (2013-02-25)
>   [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
>
> -- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------    See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
>        * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>        * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>        * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
>        * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports    the more detail of.
>
> -- Control frame information ----------------------------------------------- c:0006 p:0038 s:0038 e:000037 CLASS  /Users/boti/.rvm/src/ruby-head/lib/fileutils.rb:111
>   c:0005 p:0035 s:0034 e:000033 CLASS 
>   /Users/boti/.rvm/src/ruby-head/lib/fileutils.rb:107 c:0004 p:0009
>   s:0032 e:000031 TOP
>   /Users/boti/.rvm/src/ruby-head/lib/fileutils.rb:85 [FINISH] c:0003
>   p:---- s:0030 e:000029 CFUNC  :require c:0002 p:0098 s:0026 E:000f88
>   EVAL   ./tool/mkconfig.rb:11 [FINISH] c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0017a8
>   TOP    [FINISH]
>
> ./tool/mkconfig.rb:11:in `<main>' ./tool/mkconfig.rb:11:in`require'
>   /Users/boti/.rvm/src/ruby-head/lib/fileutils.rb:85:in `<top
>   (required)>' /Users/boti/.rvm/src/ruby-head/lib/fileutils.rb:107:in`
>   '
>   /Users/boti/.rvm/src/ruby-head/lib/fileutils.rb:111:in
>   `'
>
> -- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------
>
> - Loaded script: ./tool/mkconfig.rb
> - Loaded features:
>
>   0 enumerator.so
>
> [NOTE] You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or
>   extension libraries. Bug reports are welcome. For details:
>   http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
>
> make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap: 6

This is the beginning of my compiling log:

> [2013-02-24 20:58:47] make    CC = /usr/bin/gcc-4.2   LD = ld     LDSHARED
>   = /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamiclib    CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration   -fno-common -pipe     XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT   CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin12.2.0 -I./include -I.  DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -install_name /Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>   -current_version 2.0.0 -compatibility_version 2.0.0  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend       SOLIBS =

I would appreciate any help...

Comment: Have you installed the latest version of Xcode and the latest version of the command line tools?

Comment: Uff... no I am doing it right now. Thanks...

Comment: NP, just the first thing I'd look at if I were getting compiler errors. Also, please update the question with results. The answer below from @mpapis (an RVM release manager) indicates RVM is aware of the issue.

Comment: I reinstalled XCode and command line tools. And I got the same results...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
CC=clang rvm reinstall 2.0.0-p0
```

it will compile but might result in other errors later (I'm working on finding what causes the original issue).

Comment: CC=clang rvm reinstall "2.0.0-p0"
Version '2.0.0' is to confusing to select ruby interpreter.
Cannot remove unknown package ''
Version '2.0.0' is to confusing to select ruby interpreter.

Comment: @mpapis please post updates if you find out what is the original cause. I had the same problem with rbenv as well, but changing CC seemed to help.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into build errors around miniruby as well on Mac OS X 10.8.2 with XCode 4.6 and brew.

When just trying to run "rvm install 2.0.0" the result looks like this:

https://gist.github.com/polarapfel/5080946

When trying to set CC to /usr/bin/clang, the result looks like this:

https://gist.github.com/polarapfel/5081054

Either way, the result is the same for me.

Here's the funny thing about it: I can build head without a problem. I think 2.0.0p0 is not a clean build on Mac OS X and needs some more work to iron out the kinks.

--

OK, this did it for me: simply running "rvm get stable" got rid of the build problems.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using clang 3.0 with clang -v.
Otherwise, if you're using an older clang version, compile 2.0.0-p0 with gcc 4.2 using:

```
rvm install ruby --with-gcc=gcc-4.2
```

I would first remove old ruby attempt:

```
rvm remove 2.0.0-p0
```

Also make sure you've got rvm head (not stable):

```
rvm get head  --autolibs=3
```

If this should solve the miniruby / enc compile problems, then 2.0.0-p0 is a clean build, but you're using outdated compiler.  Installing the latest Xcode doesn't necessarily include the lastest clang version.