# Ruby 2.0.0 RVM fails compilation OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, ruby-2.0

Trying to install it with RVM I get the following error:

```
> [2013-02-25 10:09:24] make    CC = /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2     LD = ld
>   LDSHARED = /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamic -bundle  CFLAGS = -O3
> -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration   -pipe    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
> -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT  CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include -I/usr/local/opt/libxslt/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin12.2.0 -I./include -I.   DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libxslt/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend      SOLIBS =  linking miniruby ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-L/usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/lib'
> /Users/ale/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:111: [BUG] Stack
> consistency error (sp: 38, bp: 36) ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision
> 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
> 
> -- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------    See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
>      * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>      * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>      * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
>      * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports    the more detail of.
> 
> -- Control frame information ----------------------------------------------- c:0006 p:0038 s:0038 e:000037 CLASS  /Users/ale/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:111
> c:0005 p:0035 s:0034 e:000033 CLASS 
> /Users/ale/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:107 c:0004 p:0009
> s:0032 e:000031 TOP   
> /Users/ale/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:85 [FINISH] c:0003
> p:---- s:0030 e:000029 CFUNC  :require c:0002 p:0098 s:0026 E:001f68
> EVAL   ./tool/mkconfig.rb:11 [FINISH] c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:001848
> TOP    [FINISH]
> 
> ./tool/mkconfig.rb:11:in `<main>' ./tool/mkconfig.rb:11:in `require'
> /Users/ale/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:85:in `<top
> (required)>' /Users/ale/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:107:in
> `<module:FileUtils>'
> /Users/ale/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:111:in
> `<module:NoWrite>'
> 
> -- C level backtrace information ------------------------------------------- 0   miniruby                            0x0000000108465e24 rb_vm_bugreport + 164 1   miniruby                 
> 0x000000010833d95e report_bug + 302 2   miniruby                      
> 0x000000010833dc14 rb_bug + 180 3   miniruby                          
> 0x000000010845bea0 vm_exec_core + 32080 4   miniruby                  
> 0x000000010845c07e vm_exec + 94 5   miniruby                          
> 0x000000010845cf5a rb_iseq_eval + 266 6   miniruby                    
> 0x0000000108342572 rb_load_internal + 306 7   miniruby                
> 0x0000000108343cc1 rb_require_safe + 1313 8   miniruby                
> 0x000000010844bc54 call_cfunc_1 + 20 9   miniruby                     
> 0x0000000108452126 vm_call_cfunc + 1046 10  miniruby                  
> 0x0000000108460ce0 vm_call_method + 224 11  miniruby                  
> 0x0000000108457363 vm_exec_core + 12819 12  miniruby                  
> 0x000000010845c07e vm_exec + 94 13  miniruby                          
> 0x000000010845ce2e rb_iseq_eval_main + 206 14  miniruby               
> 0x0000000108340cdf ruby_exec_internal + 111 15  miniruby              
> 0x0000000108341cc2 ruby_run_node + 82 16  miniruby                    
> 0x00000001083080af main + 79 17  libdyld.dylib                      
> 0x00007fff8ae7b7e1 start + 0 18  ???                                
> 0x0000000000000009 0x0 + 9
> 
> -- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------
> 
> * Loaded script: ./tool/mkconfig.rb
> 
> * Loaded features:
> 
>     0 enumerator.so
> 
> [NOTE] You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or
> extension libraries. Bug reports are welcome. For details:
> http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
> 
> make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap: 6
```

Is it working for anyone else?

Comment: Same issue here also, with some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055457/error-while-installing-ruby2-with-rvm

Comment: Next time, please use "code sample" rather than "blockquote" for computer output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rvm get head` after 5pm London time today solved the problem. Guess Wayne has been fighting at it!

Ran `rvm reinstall 2.0.0`.

Still get `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator` on the rubygems installation, but the rest works.

Answer (score 6):

did you try with CC=clang
I've installed on 10.7 without any problem just a minute ago.

Comment: Just tried and it failed on rubygems this time: `Installing rubygems-2.0.0 for ruby-2.0.0-p0 ...
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/ale/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/ale/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global:/Users/ale/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/ale/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global GEM_HOME=/Users/ale/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 /Users/ale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby /Users/ale/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/setup.rb', please read /Users/ale/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: The CC=clang worked for me as well like this: `CC=clang rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Successfully installed here.

After removing my CC variable (was pointing to gcc-4.2) from .bash_profile and doing **rvm get head && rvm requirements && rvm reinstall 2.0.0**

But I get the rubygems install error.

Making some tests did not seem to be a problem. gem install works nice

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late here but had the same issue. I installed RVM and Ruby 2.0 with the following command and received the same error.

`curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

Make sure to restart Terminal and then run `rvm get head`

Worked here.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the ruby 2.0 head.  See the link to the specific issue below.  As an alternative to pulling the head, you also fix the build issue by applying the simple patch described in the issue.

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8171

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did that worked for me when "rvm install 2.0.0" failed.

Ensure that you have the latest Xcode installed from the App Store.

I then removed rvm with

```
rvm implode
```

And then reinstalled rvm (see [rvm.io](http://rvm.io)) with

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then I did a

```
rvm install 2.0.0
```

which worked.