# Segmentation fault while compiling ruby 1.9.3p392 with OpenSSL 1.0.1e installed

Tags: ruby, openssl, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to have my Rails website running on my fresh installation of Mountain Lion Server. Not using RVM, because I don't need many rails or ruby installations. Configuring ruby and rails to run smoothly is a pain in the ass.

Compiled the newest version of OpenSSL with these commands:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ darwin64-x86_64-cc
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Now when I type I get this:

```
grid:ruby-1.9.3-p392 Clu$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

When I try to configure Ruby from source, I get to Segmentation Fault:

```
compiling md5init.c
compiling md5ossl.c
linking shared-object digest/md5.bundle
installing default md5 libraries
compiling rmd160init.c
compiling rmd160ossl.c
linking shared-object digest/rmd160.bundle
installing default rmd160 libraries
compiling sha1init.c
compiling sha1ossl.c
linking shared-object digest/sha1.bundle
collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault: 11]
make[2]: *** [../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin12.2.1/digest/sha1.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/digest/sha1/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Comment: Why not using rvm?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064626/ruby-2-0-0-rvm-fails-compilation-os-x-10-8-2-mountain-lion/15064931?noredirect=1#comment21187088_15064931

Comment: Trying to do it without RVM, as this is for a server environment, not client. Don't need many ruby / rails installations, just one. I'll go with RVM if it won't find a solution.